# PInvoke a macro in native shared library

Tags: c#, openssl, shared-libraries, pinvoke

In OpenSSL, the function `SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(...)` is defined as follows:

```
# define SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx,m) \
        SSL_CTX_ctrl(ctx,SSL_CTRL_SET_SESS_CACHE_MODE,m,NULL)
```

I'm not a c programmer, but I *think* that is a macro. In C#, I am trying to use that function like so:

```
[DllImport(SSLDLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern long SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(IntPtr ctx, long mode);
```

And I get:

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point
>   named 'SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode' in shared library 'libssl.so'.

I'm using .net core 2.2 on linux x64 and OpenSSL v1.1.1c.

I suspect it's something to do with the act that it's a macro (if it is...). Any ideas?

Comment: Since `SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode` is a macro, the function would be `SSL_CTX_ctrl` (with 4 arguments)

Comment: @SimonMourier Are you saying you can't call macros with PInvoke?

Comment: Nope, you can't. Macro is a preprocessing concept (=text substitution phase that happens before compilation)

Comment: @SimonMourier I find it mind boggling that a library like OpenSSL would expose high level api functions through macros... How much more work could it be to just implement it as a function... Ughhh.... Thanks for the help!